# angular-onscreen-material-keyboard Custom Layout

Tags: angular

i have this code to implement custom layout

in app.module.ts

```
import { MatKeyboardModule, MAT_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS, KeyboardClassKey } from 'angular-onscreen-material-keyboard';
const customLayouts = {

    numerico: {
        name: 'Tastierino Numerico',
        keys: [
            ['1', '2', '3'],
            ['4', '5', '6'],
            ['7', '8', '9'],
            ['.', '0', KeyboardClassKey.Enter],
        ],
        lang: ['it-IT']
    },
    default: {
        name: 'Default',
        keys: [
            ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P'],
            ['A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
            ['{shift}', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', '{bksp}'],
            ['{space}', '{enter}']
        ],
        lang: ['it-IT']
    }
};


providers: [  
    {
      provide: MAT_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS,
      useValue: customLayouts
    },
```

but special key ENTER it does not work.

Can you help me?

I expect the special keys to work

Answer (score 0):

La soluzione è:

```
const customLayouts = {

numerico: {
    name: 'Tastierino Numerico',
    keys: [
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6'],
        ['7', '8', '9'],
        ['.', '0', [KeyboardClassKey.Bksp]],
        [[KeyboardClassKey.Enter]]
    ],
    lang: ['protocol-notes-text']
},
default: {
    name: 'Default',
    keys: [
        [['`'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9'], ['0'], [KeyboardClassKey.Bksp]],
        [['Q'], ['W'], ['E'], ['R'], ['T'], ['Y'], ['U'], ['I'], ['O'], ['P'], ['['], [']'], ['\'']],
        [['A'], ['S'], ['D'], ['F'], ['H'], ['J'], ['K'], ['L'], [';'], [',']],
        [['Z'], ['X'], ['C'], ['V'], ['B'], ['N'], ['M'], [','], ['.'], [KeyboardClassKey.Enter]],
        [[KeyboardClassKey.Space]]
    ],
    lang: ['it-IT']
}
};
```